# How to calculate time difference with dynamic timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with javascript, And right now i am calculate datetime, means i am getting "difference" of "old_date"(fetching from db) and "current datetime"
But i want to get difference with "dynamic timezone" (saved in database)

```js
var timezone = "<?php echo $timezone; ?>";  // getting from db
var enddate  = "<?php echo $new_date; ?>";  // getting from db
var countDownDate = new Date(enddate).getTime();
var now           = new Date().getTime();  // Get today's date and time
var distance      = countDownDate - now;   // getting difference
```

Comment: I think you should understand that it is impossible to answer you as long as we ignore the string values returned by your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the moment-timezone library in js , something like this

```
var timezone = "<?php echo $timezone; ?>";  // getting from db
var enddate  = "<?php echo $new_date; ?>";  // getting from db
var countDownDate = moment.tz(enddate, timezone).valueOf();  // convert enddate to timezone and get timestamp
var now           = moment().valueOf();  // Get today's date and time in the current timezone
var distance      = countDownDate - now;   // getting difference
```